# Passing props from component to static method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  <Modal onToggleModal={this.onToggleModal}>
    <Modal.Header onToggleModal={this.onToggleModal}>
      <h1>Modal header</h1>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <ProductDescription data={this.props.data} />
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <h1>Modal footer</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onAddToCart}>
        Buy now
      </button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

Is it possible to pass the `onToggleModal` method from `Modal` directly to `Modal.Header` ( which is a static method that returns a component ), being that I cant access `this.props` from `Modal` inside the static method ?

The modal component

```
export default class Modal extends React.Component<IProps> {
  static Header = props => <ModalHeader onToggleModal={props.onToggleModal}>{props.children}</ModalHeader>; }
```

The ModalHeader component

```
const ModalHeader: React.SFC<IProps> = props =>  {
    return (
      <div className="modal-header">
        <button className="trigger" onClick={props.onToggleModal}>
          <i className="fa fa-times close" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `1) ` Please mention which library are you using? `2) ` What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Abdullah I'm using react. What I'm trying to achieve is passing the `onToggleModal` method through props directly from the `Modal` component to a static method `Header` that returns a component.

Comment: let me rephrase. `1)`  I meant which library are you using for `Modal`. Is it `react-bootstrap`  or `reactstrap` or other? `2)` What you want to achieve by passing `onToggleModal` prop to `Header` component?

Comment: @Abdullah Its not a library, I've made the `Modal` component myself. I want to use `onToggleModal` on `Header` as callback for an event.

Comment: alright. This shouldn't be an issue. Please share code of your `Modal` component. And on what event you to execute that callback function.

Comment: @Abdullah Edited the question.